# SyncFusion Scheduler - struggling to obtain appointment details

Tags: c#, maui, scheduler, syncfusion

I have a .Net MAUI app (target platform And, iOS & Win)
im trying to use the SyncFusion Scheduler for the first time..

I have everything working but I'm struggling to obtain appointment details when I tap on the scheduler..

XAML:

```
<scheduler:SfScheduler x:Name="calendar" View="Month" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" AllowedViews="Week ,Month"   
                             TodayHighlightBrush="Gray" AppointmentsSource=" {Binding SchedulerEvents}" Tapped="calendar_Tapped" >

            <scheduler:SfScheduler.MonthView>
                <scheduler:SchedulerMonthView AppointmentDisplayMode="Indicator"  />
            </scheduler:SfScheduler.MonthView>

            <scheduler:SfScheduler.BindingContext >
                <local:SchedulerControlViewModel>
                    
                </local:SchedulerControlViewModel>
            </scheduler:SfScheduler.BindingContext>
</scheduler:SfScheduler>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void calendar_Tapped(object sender, SchedulerTappedEventArgs e)
    {


       

        if (e.Appointments.Count < 0)
        {
            //No Appointment - no problem
        }
        else
        {

            //Appointment on date tapped

        //// HOW DO I GET THE APPOINTMENT DETAILS FROM e.Appointments (such as the appointment subject.
        }

    }
```

View Model:

```
namespace MyGolfSocietyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class  SchedulerControlViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<SchedulerAppointment> SchedulerEvents { get; set; }
        public SchedulerControlViewModel()
        {

            this.SchedulerEvents = new ObservableCollection<SchedulerAppointment>
            {
                new SchedulerAppointment
                {
                    StartTime = new DateTime(2023, 8, 5,00,01,01),
                    EndTime = new DateTime(2023, 8, 5,23,01,01),
                    Subject = "TEST Appointment",
                    IsAllDay = true 
 
                }
           };

        }

    }
}
```

The Tapped event handler "calendar_Tapped" triggers ok but im struggling to get the content of the Appointments..
im sure this is super basic c# but im really struggling - hoping you guys can help me please

I can see through the debug logs (immediate window) data is being retunred from the View Model:

```
?e.Appointments
Count = 1
    [0]: {Syncfusion.Maui.Scheduler.SchedulerAppointment}
?e.Appointments[0]
{Syncfusion.Maui.Scheduler.SchedulerAppointment}
    base: {Syncfusion.Maui.Scheduler.SchedulerRegionBase}
    ActualEndTime: {System.DateTime}
    ActualStartTime: {System.DateTime}
    DataItem: (null)
    EndTimeZone: {System.TimeZoneInfo}
    Id: 311937363
    IsAllDay: true
    IsReadOnly: false
    Location: ""
    Notes: ""
    RecurrenceId: (null)
    Reminders: (null)
    StartTimeZone: {System.TimeZoneInfo}
    Subject: "TEST Appointment"
    Type: Syncfusion.Maui.Scheduler.SchedulerAppointmentType.Normal
```

Comment: `e.Appointments[0].Subject`, etc

Comment: No thats what I assumed:


Immediate window:

?e.Appointments[0].Subject
Item is null

Comment: VS Error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Subject' and no accessible extension method 'Subject' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) MyGolfSocietyApp (net7.0-android) C:\Users\Chris\source\repos\MyGolfSocietyApp\MyGolfSocietyApp\Views\EventsView.xaml.cs 58 Active

Comment: according to the docs, `public ReadOnlyCollection<object> Appointments { get; }` so you will need to cast it

Comment: Yeah I saw that but wasnt sure what im casting it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Appointments` is a collection of `object`

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<object> Appointments { get; }
```

so you will need to cast it

```
((SchedulerAppointment)e.Appointments[0]).Subject
```